# Взаимодействие со сторонними Android-приложениями

Tags: java, android

Есть готовое приложение, которое работает автономно, т.е. выполняет определенные действия, на основании введенных пользователем данных, и выводит результат. Необходимо, чтобы данное приложение выполняло те же действия, но по команде от сторонних приложений и возвращало результат стороннему приложению. Т.е. стороннее приложение должно вызвать Activity моего приложения, передав несколько параметров, мое приложение должно активироваться, собрать дополнительную информацию у пользователя, вызвав другие активити, выполнить определенные действия по взаимодействию с хостом и верную вызвавшему приложению результат. Примерно это должно выглядеть так:

```
third-party app: Activity1 -> Activity2 (call my Activity with params) -> Activity2 (recive result from my app, in focus)

my app: Activity1 - Activity2 (recive params, in focus) -> Activity3 -> Activity4 (start Thread) ->Activity5 (return result)
```

Механизм взаимодействия должен быть универсальным, чтобы любой сторонний разработчик мог взаимодействовать с моим приложением. Вопрос, как это лучше реализовать?

На ум приходит взаимодействие через Broadcasts. Стороннее приложение шлет Broadcast, в своем приложении я его получаю, и вызываю Activity2 с флагами Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. Выполняю действия и Activity5 шлет другой Broadcast с результатом, сторонее приложение его перехватывает. Не знаю насколько это решение правильное, поэтому и спрашиваю совет. Как лучше это организовать?

P.S. В идеале, чтобы стороннее приложение стартовало мое, если оно не запущено.

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Как вообще универсальный вариант могу предложить сваять в Вашем приложении API и обращаться к нему через localhost например.

Comment: Настраиваете интент фильтры в своём приложении и обрабатываете входящие запросы. Подробнее в [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html)

Answer (score 2):

Стандартный механизм предусмотренный в Android это `Intent`

подробно [описано здесь](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)

Грубо говоря, вы должны продекларировать в манифесте приложения какие действия ваше приложение может выполнять, какие данные при этом ему надо подать на вход.

Вызывающее приложение может просто воспользоваться вызовом вашего активити через `startActivity()` или `startActivityForResult()` (если ожидается результат).

Comment: Но в этом случае результат должна передавать активити, которую вызвали?! Т.е. в моем случае это Activity2, в случае с Broadcast, результат может передать Activity5.

Comment: Конечно, это же полная аналогия с функциями: вы вызываете функцию с определенными параметрами, она может вызвать другую функцию, та третью все они могут по цепочке вернуть результат, но конечный результат возвращает тот кого вызвали первым. Не очень понимаю, что вас так смущает - надеюсь, это не задевает ваши религиозные чувства :)

Comment: Нужно делать Finish() активити, чтобы вернуть результат. А мне бы этого не хотелось, т.к. Activity2 это главное меню и по сути менеджер других активностей. Пока я не сделаю finish(), сторонее приложение не получит результат.